# Perfect Topaz, imperfect profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, contests

Earned the Perfect Topaz fairly early in the contest, but the question I earned it for got closed as a duplicate: [What does the monster suffix "Chains" do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/67690/16350)
Now my profile displays a conundrum:
[image: Screenshot of Acts&Gems in my profile. The Perfect Topaz slot has the gem in it, but on mouseover displays 0/1 fast answers]

Collapse the waveform for me, please!

Comment: I'm glad the tradition of telling your teacher that you were given credit for an incorrect answer lives on outside the realm of academia. This has been reported and someone will be here shortly to take care of it. ♪

Comment: In my eighth grade math class, we would grade each other's quizzes. However, if you marked a problem as wrong on your partner's quiz and it turned out their answer was right, it meant points off of your own.

Comment: Nice, same here.  I used my own paper as the grading key to ensure I'd learn my lesson if I got something wrong :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. Your profile is perfect again!